# How do I install and run a ROS Package?

Tags: ros, installation, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's use this one for example

h.ttp://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?distro=&name=camera_application

In terminal, what are the steps to install and run this package?

I know its a noob question but I didn't see anything in the tutorials about how to install a package from ROS.org

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60570/how-do-i-install-and-run-a-ros-package?/) by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2013-04-12

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-12**:
Are you interested in that one specifically or ROS packages in general. The example you picked is somewhat more complex. It seems to be for web apps (not "only" ROS) and it looks to me to not be maintained anymore.

**Comment by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on 2013-04-12**:
ROS Packages in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let me pick a simple one without specialties: [rxparamedit](http://ros.org/wiki/rxparamedit).

Given you installed from packages in Ubuntu, the first step would be to check if there already is a debian package that you can just install. Usually that is named `ros-<distro>-<stack/metapackage>`. The nav-bar in the wiki shows the stack a package is in, which in this case would be freiburg_tools. For fuerte you'll find that `sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-freiburg-tools` works.

If there is no deb package, you have to install by sources. [rosws/ws_tool](http://www.ros.org/doc/independent/api/rosinstall/html/) is recommended for that. The wiki page should list a source URL, e.g. https://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/freiburg_tools. The rosws tutorials show how to do this in more detail, but basically `rosws set --svn https://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/freiburg_tools` and `rosws update` should do the trick.

Next, build the package by `rosdep install rxparamedit` and `rosmake rxparamedit` or `catkin_make` if the package is catkinized .

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is there no way you could install the package alone without the stack?

---

Originally posted by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) with karma: 90 on 2015-08-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-08-27**:
You can only install, what is released as a unit (e.g. as one deb package). If ROS packages are released by package or together with others depends on the maintainer.